# Get name from another table with id on another table

Tags: laravel

**Using Laravel 9**

I have two tables "objective" and "objective_sets". The objective table contains the id of objective_sets entity as foreign key with other data. When I get the data from objective table I get:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "subject_id": 1,
        "set_id": 1,
        "file": "1660481752_data.xlsx",
        "created_at": "2022-08-14T12:55:52.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-08-14T12:55:52.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "subject_id": 1,
        "set_id": 2,
        "file": "1660481767_data.xlsx",
        "created_at": "2022-08-14T12:56:07.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-08-14T12:56:07.000000Z"
    },
    
]
```

This output is obtained by (only subjects with id 1 is taken):

```
$sets = Objective::where('subject_id', $id)->get();
```

Now, I need the name of set using set_id from same objective table.

The objective_sets contains only id, name, created_at and updated_at

Comment: Have you defined a relationship on your Objective model?

Comment: Yes I have set and subject relationship in Objective model

Comment: Have a read of the docs on [eager loading relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) which I suspect is what you’re after.

Comment: The main problem is I am making an api so I need the details of set within the objective output json.

Comment: The fact it’s an API is irrelevant. Have a read of the docs and implement it and take a look at the resulting data. I think you’ll find it returns a collection with the relationship nested. You can use Laravel resources to format the response accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

$sets = Objective::with('relationship_function_name')->where('subject_id', $id)->get();

it will add the relation object

or

use Eloquent: API Resources

check this https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources#relationships